# WinAPI functions in new .exe

Tags: winapi, assembly, portable-executable

I've been looking recently into creating a new native language. I understand the (very) basics of the PE format and I've grabbed an assembler with a fairly kind interface off the webs, which I've successfully used to implement some simple functions. But I've run into a problem using functions from a library. The only way that I've called library functions from a dynamically compiled function previously is to pass in the function pointer manually- something I can't do if I create PE files and execute them in their own process. Now, I'm not planning on using the CRT, but I will need access to the Win API to implement my own standard libraries. How do I generate a reference to a WinAPI function so that the PE loader will patch it up?

Comment: Is using a linker *verboten* too?

Comment: @Hans: I will be using a linker- mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write an import table. It's basically a list of function names that you wish to use in your application. It's pointed to by the PE header. The loader loads the DLL files into the process memory space for you, finds the requested function in their export table and leaves the address for it in the import table. You then usually dereference that and `jmp` there.

Check out [Izelion's assembly tutorial](http://win32assembly.online.fr/pe-tut6.html) for the full details and for asm examples.

Comment: So, basically, I make a space for a pointer, and then the rest of the magic is done via the PE loader and format.

Comment: Yeah, only the pointer has to be part of a very specific structure.

Comment: For calling regular function pointers, do I still need to perform this trick? And- what is the difference between call and jmp?

Comment: You have the address for your own functions, so you don't need this trick. It's only there to get the address of imported/WinAPI functions that may move around in the loaded DLL or with it. As for jmp/call, use call as it makes sure the function has a context to return to.

Answer (score 0):

How about starting by emitting C instead of assembly? Then writing directly to ASM is just an optimization.

I'm not being facetious: most compilers turn out some kind of intermediate code before the final native code pass.

I realize you're trying to get away from all the null-delmited rigmarole, but you'll need that for the WinAPI functions anyway.

Re-reading your question: you do realize that you can get the WinAPI function addresses by calling LoadLibrary(), then calling GetProcAddress(), and then setting up the call...right?

If you want to see how to bootstrap this from pure assembly: the old SDKs had ASM sample code, probably the new ones still do. If they don't, the DDK will.

Comment: I know. Half the reason I don't emit C is because I don't want to be tied to the CRT, and const char* strings, and #include, and suchlike. The other reason is because I only have a just-in-time assembler. Right now, I absolutely will generate an AST and an intermediary code and suchlike, but I want to make sure that my system as a whole works before I get around to implement the whole lot. Feasibility study, if you will.

Comment: LoadLibrary is part of the WinAPI. How am I going to use it without access to the WinAPI?

Comment: It's in KERNEL, which is automatically mapped into your process from the get-go.  If it wasn't, then how would you or the system be able to load any of the rest of the libraries, including KERNEL?